# Jmeter difference properties

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, there are different property types. From command line, it can be passed parameters as -D, -J and -G. I don't understand their difference.

```
jmeter -n -t testplan.jmx -l result.jtl -Gproperty1 -Jproperty2 -Dproperty3
```

Calling for in test plan:

```
${__P(property)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `-D` - is for [Java System properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), it can be referred using [System.getProperty() function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) in scripting. Normally you should use it for setting or amending JVM system property like user locale, instructing JMeter to use client-side certificates, pointing JMeter to use custom truststore, etc.
2. `-J` is for JMeter properties, it can be referred using `props.get()` function in scripting or [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) functions anywhere else
3. `-G` is for "global" properties, when you [run JMeter in distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) you can use it for passing properties to JMeter slaves

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thank a lot, but I don't still understand function of -G params. Firstly, what is global variable. Also it can be passed parameters to slaves with -J

Comment: To individual slaves you can pass properties via `-J`. However if you want to pass the same set of properties from the master to all slaves centrally - use `-G`

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, In test plan there are In Jmeter, there are like ${__P(property)} statement, jmeter search keys in *.properties.  But if it is passed with cmd property file is overriden. Thus, Doesn't it pass all slaves when the parameter is -Jproperty?

Comment: If you use `-J` on master the property won't be propagated to any slaves, it will be applied to master only

Comment: I understand, Can we say then? -J params is useless for distibuted tests.